# How to use Regex to parse variable length string in Google Application Scripts

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

Trying to extract the alphanumeric parts of a variable length string with a known pattern using Regex in Google Application Scripts. Pattern repeats n times as follows (XXXs are groups of Alphanumeric characters):
XX-XXX-X-XX-XX-........ for example ABC-AB or ABCD-AB-ABC-AA
I want to extract the alphanumeric parts into an Array if possible like e[0] = ABCD e[1] = AB e[2] = ABC .....

I tried repeated \w+ but that requires knowing the possible lengths of string. See below. Is there a way for Regex to process varying size strings? See my example code below:

```
var data1 = 'ABC-AB';
var data2 = 'ABCD-AB-ABCD-AA';

var regex1 = new RegExp(/(\w+)-(\w+)/); 
var regex2 = new RegExp(/(\w+)/);

e = regex1.exec(data1); //stores ABC and AB as separate array elements.
```

This is fine but won't work on a string with larger size

```
e = regex2.exec(data2); //stores ABCD only as a single array element "ABCD"
```

Comment: Match the repeated string and split on `-`

Answer (score 1):

To match any length of kebab case letters:

```
var regex1 = new RegExp(/\w+(-\w+)*/)
```

For each of the matches found, split the result on dashes to get your array.

```
var array = found.split("-")
```

Comment: I tried your Regex1 suggestion: var regex1 = new RegExp(/\w+(-\w+)*/) on 'ABC-AB-ABCD-AA' and it resulted in "-AA" getting grouped in my array. I am not clear on how you intended the code to be used. Please clarify.

Comment: As per answer, regex1 will find all kebab case sequences, for example it will match `ABC-AB-ABCD-AA` from `foo ABC-AB-ABCD-AA bar`. Having extracted that match (I’m not familiar with Google apps script, so I don’t know the syntax, but I’m sure it can be done), you then split the extracted match on hyphen, which will result in the array `[ABC, AB, ABCD, AA]`

Comment: Thanks, but my question is not about extracting the kebab sequence from a random sequence. I already have a kebab sequence to being with. I am trying to find a Regex expression that will extract the Alphanumeric parts of the Kebab sequence into an array. So from  ABC-AB-ABCD-AA-(varying length) into [ABC, AB, ABCD, AA, (varying length)]

Comment: But you introduced me to .split method, which is an easier solution. So all I have to do is e = data2.split('-'); and I get the array I want. It is a curious question though if Regex can be applied to a string of variable lengths.